# How to make apache start?

Tags: apache, configuration, xampp, portability

I installed a portable XAMPP webserver at usb stick and have found that is not portable at all. I also deployed a huge site in it. So I decided to change apache and myslq configs to get some experience and save the time from reinstalling the webserver and a huge site again.

I changed pathes to relative ones in configuration files of apache and now it can't be launched and windows tells that it will close this application. Please help me to know what is going on

Here is httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "apache"
Listen 80
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin postmaster@localhost

ServerName localhost:80

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "../htdocs"
<Directory "../htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                   default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                   home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile "conf/magic"
</IfModule>

Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Include "conf/extra/httpd-proxy.conf"
Include "conf/extra/httpd-default.conf"
Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

AcceptFilter http none

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
<IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
Include "conf/extra/httpd-ajp.conf"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

and here is httpd-xampp.conf:

```
CODE: SELECT ALL
<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv MIBDIRS "../../../php/extras/mibs"
    SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
    SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "F:/xamp_port/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>

LoadFile "../php/php5ts.dll"
LoadFile "../php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php5_module "../php/php5apache2_4.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule php5_module>
    PHPINIDir "../php"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "../php/"
<Directory "../php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
          Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "../cgi-bin">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "../htdocs/xampp">
    <IfModule php5_module>
       <Files "status.php">
          php_admin_flag safe_mode off
       </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /security "../security/htdocs/"
    <Directory "../security/htdocs">
        <IfModule php5_module>
          <Files "xamppsecurity.php">
             php_admin_flag safe_mode off
          </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
   </Directory>

    Alias /licenses "../licenses/"
    <Directory "../licenses">
        Options +Indexes
        <IfModule autoindex_color_module>
            DirectoryIndexTextColor  "#000000"
            DirectoryIndexBGColor "#f8e8a0"
            DirectoryIndexLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexVLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexALinkColor "#bb3902"
        </IfModule>
        Require all granted
   </Directory>

    Alias /phpmyadmin "../phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "..">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /webalizer "../webalizer/"
    <Directory "../webalizer">
        <IfModule php5_module>
          <Files "webalizer.php">
             php_admin_flag safe_mode off
          </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</IfModule>

<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        Require local
   ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

The decision is to download and unzip zip distributive of portable version and then copy all configuration files from it. And by the way - the xampp must be placed in the root of the disk